# selecting only latesst timestamp file of a log

Tags: python, file

log directory contains log file which is a result of a sqlloader script.so everytime it run it creates a new log file with the timestamp. e.g.

SSMNAD_POST_DATE.SQL.855964.20230307001856.log
SSTMNAD_POST_DATE.SQL.2951016.20230306194622.log

I would like to select only latest file and discard the remaining file .

could you advise how do i achieve in python ?
lookin

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

[`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns all files in a directory. So use a list comprehension to create a list of only the actual log files.

Assuming the timestamp in the log file is YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, you can use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) to return the biggest date lexicographically. If it's actually YYYYDDMMHHMMSS, then you'll need to transform the string into a [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object so it is sorted properly.

Finally, loop over the list of log files and if there is more than 1 log file, call [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove) to delete the other log files (if that's what you meant by "discard").

```py
import os

LOG_DIRECTORY = r"C:\Users\Bobson Dugnutt\Log Files"

logfiles = [fn for fn in os.listdir(LOG_DIRECTORY)
            if "POST_DATE.SQL" in fn and fn.endswith(".log")]

newest_logfile = max(logfiles, key=lambda fn:fn.rsplit(".", maxsplit=2)[1])

print("Newest log file:", newest_logfile)

if len(logfiles) > 1:
    for filename in logfiles:
        if filename != newest_logfile:
            print("Deleting old log file:", filename)
            #os.remove(filename) # Uncomment this line
```

---

This updated code does much the same as above but creates a list of logfiles that all have the highest timestamp. The old code would only return one logfile, even if there were multiple files with the same timestamp.

```py
import os

LOG_DIRECTORY = r"C:\Users\Bobson Dugnutt\Log Files"

logfiles = [fn for fn in os.listdir(LOG_DIRECTORY)
            if "POST_DATE.SQL" in fn and fn.endswith(".log")]

newest_timestamp = ""
for logfile in logfiles:
    timestamp = logfile.rsplit(".", maxsplit=2)[1]
    if timestamp > newest_timestamp:
        newest_logfiles = [logfile]
        newest_timestamp = timestamp
    elif timestamp == newest_timestamp:
        newest_logfiles.append(logfile)

print("Newest logfiles:", *newest_logfiles, sep="\n")

if len(logfiles) > 1:
    for filename in logfiles:
        if filename not in newest_logfiles:
            print("Deleting old log file:", filename)
            #os.remove(filename) # Uncomment this line
```

---

This initially stores the newest log files in a dict, with the key being the first part of the log file's name, and the value being the filename of the newest version. e.g. `'ALIMT_V_CHEK_NEW_DATA':'ALIMT_V_CHEK_NEW_DATA.SQL.198464.20230319202858.log'`

At the end, a list is created with the filenames of all the newest log files.

```py
import os

LOG_DIRECTORY = r"C:\Users\Bobson Dugnutt\Log Files"

newest_logfiles = {}
for filename in os.listdir(LOG_DIRECTORY):
    if ".SQL." in filename and filename.endswith(".log"):
        name, *_, timestamp, _ = filename.split(".")
        if name not in newest_logfiles:
            newest_logfiles[name] = filename
        else:
            if timestamp > newest_logfiles[name].rsplit(".", maxsplit=2)[1]:
                print("Deleting old log file:", newest_logfiles[name])
                #os.remove(newest_logfiles[name]) # Uncomment this line
                newest_logfiles[name] = filename
            else:
                print("Deleting old log file:", filename)
                #os.remove(filename) # Uncomment this line

newest_logfiles = list(newest_logfiles.values())

print("Newest newest_logfiles:", *newest_logfiles, sep="\n")
```

When `C:\Users\Bobson Dugnutt\Log Files` contains:

```
ALIMT_V_CHEK_NEW_DATA.SQL.198464.20230319202858.log
ALIMT_V_CHEK_NEW_DATA.SQL.4216.20230319194847.log
TRMNAD_POST_DATE.SQL.2951016.20230306194622.log
TRMNAD_POST_DATE.SQL.855964.20230307001856.log
```

The output is:

```
Deleting old log file: ALIMT_V_CHEK_NEW_DATA.SQL.4216.20230319194847.log
Deleting old log file: TRMNAD_POST_DATE.SQL.2951016.20230306194622.log
Newest newest_logfiles:
ALIMT_V_CHEK_NEW_DATA.SQL.198464.20230319202858.log
TRMNAD_POST_DATE.SQL.855964.20230307001856.log
```

Comment: What do you mean by "on set of file"? Update your question with a more expansive list of log filenames.

Comment: thank you . it sort of work but only on one set of file.   out of  2 distinct file only one file is produced as output ..did a for loop but still it is not picking up the other file 
 106_ECL_TRMNAD_POST_DATE.SQL.855964.20230307001856.log

Comment: Are you saying there are other log files with the same timestamp, and you want both? Update your question with a full list of filenames in the log file directory, and also a list of log filenames as the desired/expected output.

Comment: sorry my bad ..i thought i have posted all scenario of file.. yes the log file contains list of log  file produced from different script on each run.. would like to select a latest for each set of log file    . the log directory contains files as below .                                                         TRMNAD_POST_DATE.SQL.855964.20230307001856.log
TRMNAD_POST_DATE.SQL.2951016.20230306194622.log
ALIMT_V_CHEK_NEW_DATA.SQL.4216.20230319194847.log
ALIMT_V_CHEK_NEW_DATA.SQL.198464.20230319202858.log

Comment: Okay, I think I am starting to understand, but not entirely. You say "the log file contains list of log file produced from different script on each run". What is *the* log file? What is its name? And this log file in turn contains a list of other log files. How do you differentiate between the different log files?

Comment: Also, update your question (click the "Edit" link immediately below your question) with these extra details. At the moment your question is unclear.

Comment: please discard this statment : the log file contains list of log file produced from different script on each run                                                                                                                       the actual scenario is log folder contains different set of log file  .  for one set of log file it is the collection of different timestamp file .. what  i am trying to do is to pick the latest file from the log folder for each set of file..sorry for the confusion

Comment: Okay I think I understand now. The updated code now create a list of all the logfiles that have the highest timestamp, instead of a single file.

Comment: thank you for providing your input .. however it still provide a single file.  log folder contains the below files                         TRMNAD_POST_DATE.SQL.855964.20230307001856.log TRMNAD_POST_DATE.SQL.2951016.20230306194622.log ALIMT_V_CHEK_NEW_DATA.SQL.4216.20230319194847.log ALIMT_V_CHEK_NEW_DATA.SQL.198464.20230319202858.log                                                                                              the output i am looking is      
ALIMT_V_CHEK_NEW_DATA.SQL.4216.20230319194847.log TRMNAD_POST_DATE.SQL.855964.20230307001856.log

Comment: Why is `ALIMT_V_CHEK_NEW_DATA.SQL.4216.20230319194847.log` outputted instead of `ALIMT_V_CHEK_NEW_DATA.SQL.198464.20230319202858.log`? 20230319194847 is less than 20230319202858. I assume you have made a mistake. I have updated my answer. It outputs `ALIMT_V_CHEK_NEW_DATA.SQL.198464.20230319202858.log` and `TRMNAD_POST_DATE.SQL.855964.20230307001856.log`.